# Spring programmatic transaction management caveat?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Spring supports programmatic transaction which give us fine grained control over TX management. According to Spring Documentation, One can use programmatic TX management by: 
1. utilizing Spring's TransactionTemplate:

```
transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {

protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
    try {
        updateOperation1();
        updateOperation2();
    } catch (SomeBusinessExeption ex) {
        status.setRollbackOnly();
    }
} });
```

2. leveraging PlatformTransactionManager directly(inject a PlatformTransactionManager implementation into DAO):

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
def.setName("SomeTxName");
def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED);

//txManager is a reference to PlatformTransactionManager
TransactionStatus status = txManager.getTransaction(def);
try {
  updateOperation1();
  updateOperation2();
}
catch (MyException ex) {
    txManager.rollback(status);
    throw ex;
}
txManager.commit(status);
```

for the sake of simplification, let's say we are dealing with JDBC database operation.

I am wondering for any database operations happened at `updateOperation1(),updateOperation2()` in the second snippet, either it is implemented with `JDBCTemplate` or `JDBCDaoSupport`, if not, the operation is actually not performed within any transaction, is it?

My analysis is that if we don't use `JDBCTemplate` or `JDBCDaoSupport`, we inevitably will create/retrieve connection from datasource management. the connection we get is of course not the connection used by `PlatformTransactionManager` underlying to manage transaction.

I dug Spring source code and skim related class found that `PlatformTransactionManager` will try to retrieve a connection contained in `ConnectionHolder` which in return retrieved from `TransactionSynchronizationManager`. I also found `JDBCTemplate` and `JDBCDaoSupport,` also try to get connection with similar routine from `TransactionSynchronizationManager.`

Because `TransactionSynchronizationManager` manages many resource including connection per thread(basically use `Threadlocal` to ensure one thread get its own unique instance of the managed resource)

So I think the connection retrieved by PlatformTransactionManager and `JDBCTemplate` or `JDBCDaoSupport` is just same, this can explain how spring programmatic transaction ensure `updateOperation1(),updateOperation2()` were guarded by transaction.

Is my analysis correct? if it is, why Spring documentation hasn't emphasized this caveat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's correct.

Any code that uses raw `Connection`s should obtain them from the `DataSource` in special way in order to participate in transactions managed by Spring ([12.3.8 DataSourceTransactionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-DataSourceTransactionManager)):

> Application code is required to retrieve the JDBC connection through DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSource) instead of Java EE's standard DataSource.getConnection.

Another option (if you cannot change code that calls `getConnection()`) is to wrap your `DataSource` with [`TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.html).